# What is the Pandas equivalent of top_n() in dplyr?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the Pandas equivalent of top_n() in dplyr?

In R dplyr 0.8.5:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6))
> df %>% top_n(2, wt=x)
   x
1 10
2  6
3  6
```

As the dplyr documentation highlights, note that we get more than 2 values here because there's a tie: top_n() either takes all rows with a value, or none.

My attempt in Pandas 1.0.1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6]})
df = df.sort_values('x', ascending=False)
df.groupby('x').head(2)
```

Result:

```
    x
0  10
3   6
6   6
1   4
4   3
2   1
5   1
```

Expected results:

```
   x
1 10
2  6
3  6
```

Comment: try ```df.reset_index().head(3)```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parameter `keep='all'` in [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), sorting here is not necessary:

```
df = df.nlargest(2, 'x', keep='all')
print(df)

    x
0  10
3   6
6   6
```

Answer (score 1):

IUC, try [`series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with [`series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['x'].isin(df['x'].nlargest(2))]#.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    x
0  10
3   6
6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

`top_n` in `dplyr` is superseded by `slice_max/slice_min`. See:

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) in python, you can do it in a similar way:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datar.all import f, slice_max
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6]})
>>> df
        x
  <int64>
0      10
1       4
2       1
3       6
4       3
5       1
6       6
>>> df >> slice_max(n=3, order_by=f.x)
        x
  <int64>
0      10
3       6
6       6
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `datar` package.